# django models related manager

Tags: django, model

I want to develop DJANGO Application for rooms booking.
I want to use following TWO models.

```
class Room(models.Model):  
    room_no = models.IntegerField()
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.remarks

class Roombooking(models.Model):    
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name= 'roombookingforroom', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booked_for_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    booked_by = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default='')
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=100,)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["suit", "booked_for_date"],
                name="unique_room_date",
            ),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room.remarks
```

To avoid assigning one room to 2 different persons on any day, “ UniqueConstraint” is used.

Now, how to query the list of rooms which are vacant from DATE1 to DATE2

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter the room booking by date

gte = greater than or equal to

lte = lower than or equal to

```
query = Roombooking.objects.filter(booked_for_date__gte=DATE1, booked_for_date__lte=DATE2)
```

**Note that DATE1 and DATE2 should be datetime type*

You can have a look on [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#gt)

Comment: I want the rooms VACANT from DATE1 to DATE2. After booking the rooms , information on LEFT out rooms. Not the information on "Roombookings" from DATE1 to DATE2